# Sql Script Creating issue for new database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create sql script which will work on server to check if database not exists then create new and if it exist then update its tables and SP's. but the problem is incase of its not exist , it create database but the tables and sp's gone to master database.

sample.

```
    DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128)
    SET @dbname = N'ABC'

    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE ('[' + 
    name + ']' = @dbname OR name = @dbname)))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'New Database '
        CREATE DATABASE [ABC];
        USE ABC;  // This use statement is not working i supposed

        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product_Container](
            [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [ContainerID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [AssociatedProductID] [int] NOT NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY]


         END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
           PRINT 'Existing Database '
        END
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is running code.

```
begin
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128), @command1 nvarchar(max), @command2 nvarchar(max)
SET @dbname = N'ABC'
    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = @dbname))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'New Database Creating' + @dbname
        set @command1 = 'USE MASTER; CREATE DATABASE ' + @dbname + '; '
        --set @command += 'USE ' + @dbname + '; '

        set @command2 = 'CREATE TABLE [ABC].[dbo].[Product_Container](
            [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [ContainerID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [AssociatedProductID] [int] NOT NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY];'

         END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
           PRINT 'Existing Database ' + @dbname
        END
    exec sp_executesql @command1;
    exec sp_executesql @command2;
    end;
```

Comment: Go splits the batches if you want it to be enforced you will have to use Dynamic sequel

Comment: sorry i did't got you

Answer (score 0):

The database name in the `USE` statement is interpreted as the script is being parsed;
*before* the script is being executed.
Consequently, `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` cannot be in the same batch.

I suggest to split up the script in multiple batches.
This means you will have to get rid of the `IF` statement.
I suggest to use an exception instead.

Splitting up the script in batches is not as straightforward as it seems.
Even an exception will not prevent the second batch from executing even though the first batch failed.
As proposed by @clifton_h, you could use dynamic SQL.
Which means, put the entire second part in a string.
I don't particularly like that approach, because it makes the script harder to maintain.

```
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128) = N'ABC';
IF DB_ID(@dbname) IS NOT NULL THROW 51000, 'Existing Database.', 1;
PRINT 'New Database.';
CREATE DATABASE [ABC];
EXEC('
    USE ABC;
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product_Container](
        [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [ContainerID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [AssociatedProductID] [int] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY];
');
```

An alternative is to simply make two scripts, and then use a batchfile or Powershell script to execute one after that other, taking into account any exceptions thrown by the first script.

The first script creates the database:

```
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128) = N'ABC';
IF DB_ID(@dbname) IS NOT NULL THROW 51000, 'Existing Database.', 1;
PRINT 'New Database.';
CREATE DATABASE [ABC];
```

The second script creates the tables and other database objects:

```
USE ABC;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product_Container](
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContainerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssociatedProductID] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Finally, a sample batch file to put it all together:

```
@echo off
echo Script 1...
sqlcmd -b -E -i script1.sql
if errorlevel 1 goto end
echo Script 2...
sqlcmd -b -E -i script2.sql
if errorlevel 1 goto end
echo Successfully completed.
:end
```